# PHP Create class variables

Tags: php, variables, static

Is any way to create class static var inside method?
something like this..

```
class foo {

    public function bind($name, $value) {
         self::$name = $value;
    }

};
```

or is there other solution to bind variables to class and later use it without long and ugly syntax "$this->"

Comment: I think self::$name is much uglier than $this->name...

Comment: I don't get your code, what does it do?

Comment: If you plan to bind an unknown number of variables, you could make your class implement ArrayAccess

Comment: @kennypu matter of taste

Comment: @non true. and I think Adam is talking about this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php Personally, If i have unknown variables, I would just create a class variable named, lets say, variables that is an array, then bind would just do: $this->variables[$name] = $value

Comment: I fail to see how `self::$name` is shorter than `$this->name`?? And what's your code doing anyway?

Comment: I would like to do simple template lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. But if you'd like to attach variables at runtime, you could do this:

```
abstract class RuntimeVariableBinder
{
    protected $__dict__ = array();

    protected function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->__dict__[$name])) {
            return $this->__dict__[$name];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->__dict__[$name] = $value;
    }
}


class Foo
extends RuntimeVariableBinder
{
    // Explicitly allow calling code to get/set variables
    public function __get($name) {
        return parent::__get($name);
    }
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        parent::__set($name, $value);
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar = "Hello, world!";
echo $foo->bar; // Prints "Hello, world!"
```

http://codepad.org/H9bz2uVp

Answer (score 1):

Using `self` would result in a fatal error, as the property is undeclared. You would have to use `$this` which would then be accessible as a public variable:

```
<?php
class foo { 
    public function bind($name, $value) {
         $this->$name = $value;
    }

}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bind('bar','Hello World');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($foo);
echo $foo->bar;
echo '</pre>';?>
```

Comment: But entirely dependent on code-flow and program state in terms of whether or not the variable exists or what its value might be. That makes it near enough private for any practical use.